# Solving the inequality: $1\leq \cot^2(x)\leq 3$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I want to solve the following inequality:

$$1\leq \cot^2(x)\leq 3.$$

but I'm unsure of how to handle the positive and negative square roots.
If I take the square of the inequality, just focusing on the posive square roots, I get:

$$1\leq \cot^2(x)\leq 3 \Leftrightarrow \mathrm{arccot}(1)\leq x \leq \mathrm{arccot}(3) \Leftrightarrow \frac{\pi}{4} \leq \cot(x)\leq \frac{\pi}{6}.$$

which is clearly wrong. So, what's the method to solve this?

Thanks!
Alexander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember: $a\leq x^2\leq b$ (where $a,b\geq 0$) is equivalent to $\sqrt{a}\leq\lvert x\rvert\leq \sqrt{b}$. So, in this case, you want to solve
$$
1\leq\lvert\cot(x)\rvert\leq\sqrt{3},
$$
or equivalently
$$
-\sqrt{3}\leq \cot(x)\leq-1\qquad\text{or}\qquad1\leq\cot(x)\leq\sqrt{3}.
$$

Comment: Ok thank you, so far it's clear.  But the last step $1 \leq cot(x) \leq \sqrt{3}$ gets $\pi /6 \leq x \leq \pi /4$. If I evaluate the inequalities separately I get the inequality mentioned above.

Comment: Right, but you still have to deal with $-\sqrt{3}\leq\cot(x)\leq-1$, which will give you a separate range.  The inequality you want is satisfied whenever EITHER of these last two inequalities are satisfied

Comment: Yes but $1 \leq cot(x) $ implies $\pi /4 \leq x$ and $cot(x) \leq \sqrt{3}$ implies $x \leq \pi /6$ and thus $\pi /4 \leq x \leq \pi/6$,  which should be the other way around, right?  What's wrong here?

Comment: The cotangent is a decreasing function on $[0,\pi]$. So, $1\leq \cot(x)$ implies $x\leq\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
$$ 1\leq t^2\leq 3 \Leftrightarrow \left(\sqrt{1}\leq t\leq\sqrt{3}\,\right)\vee\left(-\sqrt{3}\leq t\leq-\sqrt{1}\right)$$